# Passing a computed column value to FROM_UNIXTIME in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column 'ts_min' having time since epoch in minutes

```
ts_min
--------
24429000    
24428340
24427680
```

I tried the following query to get date representation of these values

```
select ts_min, from_unixtime(ts_min*60000) from mytable;
```

from_unixtime is returning null.

```
ts_min    from_unixtime (ts_min * 60000)
----------------------------------------
24429000       NULL
24428340       NULL
24427680       NULL
```

What is the correct syntax to pass computed value from a column to from_unixtime

Comment: what result do you want obtain  ?  show a sample

Comment: Why are you multiplying by `60000` instead of just `60`? `FROM_UNIXTIME` takes seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: @DCoder That was the issue. Thanks for the pointer. I was passing milliseconds to FROM_UNIXTIME. Is there a way to get hour of day, hour of week and hour of month values using FROM_UNIXTIME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, 60 is ok. see sample:

**sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select from_unixtime(24429000*60);
+----------------------------+
| from_unixtime(24429000*60) |
+----------------------------+
| 2016-06-12 16:00:00        |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: I was passing milliseconds to from_unixtime instead of seconds. That was the issue. For a given timestapm, is there a way to get hour of day, hour of week and hour of month values using FROM_UNIXTIME or any other command

Answer (score 0):

You can use both  sec_to_time and from_unixtime

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(ts_min*60) from dual
```

or

```
select from_unixtime(ts_min*60) from dual
```